# npm scripts: node-sass not watching partial sass files

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-sass

I have this project structure:

```
src
--assets
----css
----sass
------main.scss
------_variables.scss
```

I am trying to write an npm script that will watch for changes in all of my scss files (including partials), and then only compile my main.scss file. So far nothing happens when I change my partial files until I save main.scss. What am I doing wrong?

my scripts:

```
"scripts" : {
    "sass": "node-sass src/assets/**/*.scss src/assets/css/*.css",
    "sass:watch": "npm run sass -- --watch"
  }
```

Comment: found that moving the partials to a subfolder will watch the files correctly. No idea why though.

Comment: Have had the same issue. Transferring all partials to a subfolder did the trick for me as well.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. However using subfolder does not work for me. Any advice? Here are [details of my folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75578846/how-do-i-update-my-css-when-scss-particals-are-updated).